# I cannot create my qrcode with picture (VCF file) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, vcf-vcard

MY purpose is create qrcode with vcf file dev on python3.9.6 but i got error when i put image file(image already processed to base64) on vcf file. USE qrcode library to create qrcode.
here is error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    generate_qr_code_contact()
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test.py", line 21, in generate_qr_code_contact
    img_1 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer())
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 353, in make_image
    self.make()
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 160, in make
    self.best_fit(start=self.version)
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 108, in version
    self.best_fit()
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 232, in best_fit
    self.version = bisect_left(
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 115, in version
    util.check_version(value)
  File "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qrcode/util.py", line 185, in check_version
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid version (was {version}, expected 1 to 40)")
ValueError: Invalid version (was 41, expected 1 to 40)
```

here is my code

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil import RoundedModuleDrawer
from qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import RadialGradiantColorMask

def generate_qr_code_contact():
    # Open the file in read mode
    file_path = "/Users/thitinch/Desktop/VS/VCF1.txt"  # Replace with the actual file path
    file = open(file_path, "r")

    # Read the entire contents of the file
    content = file.read()
    print(content)
    file.close()

    # Generate the QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L)
    qr.add_data(content)
    #qr_code = qrcode.make(content)

    img_1 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer())
    img_2 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask())


    # Save the QR code as an image
    #qr_code.save("contact_qr_code.png")
    img_1.save("contact_qr_code1.png")
    img_2.save("contact_qr_code2.png")



generate_qr_code_contact()
```

and here is vcf file

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:test
FN:example
ORG:เพนกวินกำหมัด
TITLE:นักกินปลา
TEL;TYPE#WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE#HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=jpeg: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
ADR;TYPE#WORK,PREF:;;999 บ้านเพนกวิน;เมืองหนาว;ฤฤ;30314;แอนต๊ากติดก้า
LABEL;TYPE#WORK,PREF:100 บ้านเพนกวิน\nเมืองหนาว\, LA 30314\nแอนต๊ากติดก้า
ADR;TYPE#HOME:;;999 บ้านเพนกวิน;เมืองหนาว;ฤฤ;30314;แอนต๊ากติดก้า
LABEL;TYPE#HOME:42 บ้านเพนกวิน St.\nเมืองหนาว\, LA 30314\nแอนต๊ากติดก้า
EMAIL:เพนกวิน@example.com
REV:2040-04-24T19:52:43Z
END:VCARD
```

I generate qr code with qrcode library,It is work right a way. but when i try with put base64 image on vcf file, it got error.
**Note**
i try VCF file with base 64 image it work on contact but not work when use thos file to generate qr code.